# UK visitor visa requirements for a self-employed father and employed mother visiting their son in the UK?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

My parents intend to visit my brother, who is working in the UK (living in his own property). I too plan to accompany my parents. At present, my parents and I live together in the Middle East. I am employed, as is my mother, although my father is self-employed.

We recognise the need of fulfilling specific conditions to be able to acquire a UK visit visa, such as:

- Sufficient funds
- Reasons to return to Middle East/not to overstay
- Sponsorship

My father has not been earning money since a year, however, given the economic conditions of the country we reside in. Further, he has transferred all of his money back to our home country, to invest in real estate. He currently does not have any money in his bank account.

My mother, on the other hand, earns money from teaching at a school. But as it happens in the Middle East, legally she is not on the school's sponsorship, and rather on my father's.
I have a stable income, as my mother, and I am on my employer's sponsorship.

Having read other answers here, such as [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e), it seems even if I or my brother sponsor our parents' travel, it seems my father would still need to show that he has enough money available at hand. And this money will need to be sufficient for my mother's expenses too, as legally she is under my father's sponsorship.
In other words, the visit applications of my parents will probably be rejected.

**Is there something we can do to prove to the UK visa officer(s) that we just intend to give our parents a tour of the UK, and that we will return to our country of residence?**

**Edit to add more info**

*Mother is under father's sponsorship*
Although my mother gets paid directly into her account by the school, not being under the school's sponsorship means she is legally still a housewife. The school will not offer an employment letter or salary slip to recognise my mother's employment.

*Nationality*
We are Pakistanis, but have been living in Saudi Arabia for 27 years.

*My travel history and visa*
I already hold a 5 year multiple visit visa for the UK, and I have been visiting every year since 2015.

*Parent's travel history*
My mother has already travelled twice to the UK. Once when we were students, and another time in 2016 on a visit visa  (when my father had funds in his account). My mother submitted her and my father's bank statement, and salary slips she was fortunately able to acquire for once.
She also travels regularly to Pakistan (at least once a year).
My father recently travelled to Pakistan with the entire family but has never been to the UK.

*Visit duration*
I plan to spend no more than 3 weeks, and my parents about a month.

Comment: Hi info_seekR. Welcome to Travel StackExchange. You wrote about your mother "legally she is not on the school's sponsorship, and rather on my father's". What does that mean in terms of payment and contracts? Does it mean she isn't paid directly, or there isn't a record of her employment? Who does get paid for what she does? Please edit the question to add this info.

Comment: @info_seekeR Although not guaranteed, and with a caveat regarding funds parking concerns, I have successfully sponsored a visit visa by sending my visitor funds in advance which were then solely available to him in his home country, explaining/proving this with bank statements & covering letter. The same person has subsequently visited without being able to show means (we stated that I was funding everything & he had no savings). Having said that, he has a job, dependent family in his home country, and no relatives in UK. The latter may be viewed negatively if your whole family is travelling.

Comment: What is your nationality? Do you & your parents have a good travel history? How long are you planning on staying in the UK?

Comment: Thank you @Traveller, I have added response to your comments in the OP.

Comment: @DJClayworth, thanks so much. I responded to your questions.

Comment: `it seems even if I or my brother sponsor our parents' travel, it seems my father would still need to show that he has enough money available at hand.` It is well established that spouses accounts belong to both partners. Your father does not need money in his bank account. If your mother could get the documents to prove she is employed, her financial status could have covered him together with title documents of his property back home. As it stands now you are in a weird situation. If you want to still apply, make sure you add a well written, clear but succinct cover letter explaining.

Comment: You could also get a solicitor to handle this. It is not a complex case so I do not expect exorbitant fees, `A cover letter does not appear anywhere in the rules; it is not required. On the other hand a well-crafted, word-smithed cover letter can carry the application and sometimes the results border on miraculous. It means a mediocre application becomes a strong one. Sadly, a sloppy, poorly-crafted letter hurts the application so you need to think it over carefully. UK solicitors with a specialty in visit visas are the best at cover letters if you decide you want to go that route.` Gayot Fow

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Thanks ever so much. Your suggestion does make sense.